# Set ng-model to a be named the same as variable rather than referencing that variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an dierective that looks like this:

```
.directive('gdInputField', function() {
    return {
        //will only work for elements, not attributes.
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<label for='{{name}}'>{{label}}</label><input name='{{key}}' id='{{name}}' type='{{type}}' ng-required='{{required}}' /><p>{{entry.1949113882}}</p>",
        scope: {
                label: '@label',
                name: '@name',
                key: "@key",
                required: "@required",
                type: "@type"
        },
    };
})
```

I wish to add the value that is set with @key as the name of the model for the input-field. If I set `ng-model='key'`. I get the string that is @key as the content of the ng-model.

This is seems to be the result:

```
$scope={
     someting: @key
}
```

What I want is:

```
$scope={
   @key: '';
}
```

if the user writes something in the input @key should update.

Also, what is the current name of the model-bidning or how could I find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as follows

```
app.directive('gdInputField', function () {
    return {
        //will only work for elements, not attributes.
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<label for='{{name}}'>{{label}}</label><input name='{{inputName}}' ng-model='key' id='{{name}}' type='{{type}}' ng-required='{{required}}' /><p>{{key}}</p>",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.inputName = attrs.key;
        },
        scope: {
            label: '@label',
            name: '@name',
            key: "=",
            required: "@required",
            type: "@type"
        },
    };
});
```

Key point is that the key should be bidirectional to be used as model.

Comment: is it the equal-sign that make the key bidirectional?

Comment: Yes. With equal-sign you can use binding. there is good article here http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/